# Program works incorrect without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, libraries

I don't have any references to local file system. When I start my program with Eclipse, it works correctly. But when I export it as Runnable jar file , my program starts normally, works one cycle in "while" and just don't enter second time. I mean there is no exit from while cycle. It just goes to the end of cycle and does't enter again.

Also there isn't any exceptions. It seems that just one of libraries just refuses to do its' job. Also I have all libraries in different folders, but as I know, anyway all of them exports to project while compiling. Any ideas?

```
do {
//messaging, that it still works. Second time it even doesn't get there
            threadController.log("Working");
            link = null;
            try {
                currentProxy = threadController.getProxy();
                link = threadController.getPageLink(currentProxy);
                HashMap<String, String> map = null;
                map = parser.loadFullInfo(currentProxy, link);
                if (map != null) {
                    threadController.addMap(map);
                    threadController.incLinksProcessed();
                    Thread.sleep(threadController.getRequestTimeout());
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
            } catch (BadProxyException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                if (link == null) {
                    link = "";
                } else {
                    threadController.addLinkBack(link);
                }
            } catch (InvalidLinkFormatException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                ThreadController.showInfoDialog("Ошибка", "Плохая ссылка в списке");
                link = "";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                if (link != null) {
                    threadController.addLinkBack(link);
                } else
                    link = "";
            } catch (NoProxiesException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                ThreadController.showInfoDialog("Ошибка", "В указанных файлах отсутсвуют прокси");
                link = null;
            } catch (CaptchaException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                if (link == null) {
                    link = "";
                } else {
                    threadController.addLinkBack(link);
                }
                if (currentProxy.getProxy() == Proxy.NO_PROXY) {
                    threadController.log("Превышен лимит запросов для вашего ip адреса. Идет запрос капчи. Начните использовать прокси");
                } else {
                    threadController.log("Превышет лимит запросов для прокси: " + currentProxy.getProxy().toString() + ". Идет запрос капчи. Обновите список прокси.");
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                if (link != null) {
                    try {
                        threadController.addLinkBack(link);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        threadController.log(e.toString());
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (TooMuchWaitException e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                link = "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                threadController.log(e.toString());
                //there works finally block and then it doesn't enter in cycle again, though it doesn't quit out of it (I printed my two conditions in "while" every cycle). It just stays like there occured some error or smth.
            } finally {
                threadController.log("I'm alive");
            }
        } while (link != null && !threadController.isStopped());
```

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to help you without any code snippet.

Comment: A library on strike? Darn! the Library Unions!

Comment: Added some code. Maybe it will help :)

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Use remote debugger or add print statements to check why your program exits the loop. There can be 2 reasons: `link == null` or `threadController.isStopped() == true`. link can be null for example if `MalformedUrlException` or `InterruptedException` is thrown.

Comment: I printed statements. I did everything :) I used to show boolean states of link == null and threadController.isStopped() before check. The problem is (as I wrote at first post) it DOES NOT QUIT OUT OF CYCLE. It just doesn't want to enter second time.